# How to find key of hash in jsonb in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonb

**Example**
Model Home, column: animals.
Inside animals jsonb like this:

```
dogs: {
  dog1: { attributes...},
  dog2: { attributes...},
  ...
}
```

**Question**
How can I find dog1 only by the key("dog1")

Comment: Could you provide the database, model, and migration? What have you tried so far? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by Active Record natively. You'll have to write some custom where clauses. For example in Postgres, see documentation here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html.

Some examples are listed here: https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails, under the "Querying your jsonb column" section!

```
# preferences->twitter OR preferences->github
User.where('preferences ?| array[:keys]', keys: ['twitter', 'github'])
```